# Imagine two patients presenting for emergency care with aching jaw pain

Tags: word-usage

> Imagine two patients presenting for emergency care with aching jaw pain.

Does the verb 'present' can be used as an intransitive one and like 'presenting' as a present participle here? Does the sentence look idiomatic? What's the meaning of "presenting"?

Comment: To avoid redundancy, 'jaw pain' or 'aching jaw'.

Comment: Incidentally, "Does ... can ..." is not grammatical. You need the auxiliary _do (does, did)_ for a quesiton **except** where there is another auxiliary (_be_, _have_ or a modal such as _can_). "Can the verb 'present' be used ... ?"

Comment: @Colin Fine Thanks for your finding. It was my pure mistake made in a hurry.

Answer (score 2):

*Can the verb 'present' be used as an intransitive one?* Yes, this is a specialised medical use of the word.

MEDICINE :
(of a patient) come forward for initial medical examination for a particular condition or symptom.
"the patient presented with mild clinical encephalopathy" (Oxford Languages)

Comment: Sorry but can you provide the link, I have searched for the exact meaning but was unable to find one that matches yours thanks

Comment: Sorry but I can't; it's just from one of English problems.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/present#Verb, sense 11.

Comment: @DialFrost - When I google _[word] definition_, the first result is the definition from Oxford Languages. Often you have to click on "Translations and more definitions" to get the full range of meanings. In this case, it's the second sense of _present_, definition 5.

Comment: @KateBunting Not just medical, surely! One presents for all kinds of things - *She presented for work on her first day, smiling and smart in dress*; *To obtain your certificate you need to present yourself to the Dean*. I've heard it also used in the form *He presents well at inteview* meaning he made a good general first impression.  It is formal, but difficult to replicate in another way.  Psychotherapists talk about *presenting problems* - which often differ markedly from the underlying real issue that is affecting someone.

Comment: @WS2 - It is the dictionaries that label the usage 'medical'! _Present yourself_ is of course transitive and so slightly different.

Comment: @ColinFine I think sense 11 applies to my question.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes even the OED which has an extremely lengthy entry on the verb - has few examples outside of obstetrics. However sense 2a (mostly ecclesiastical) is relevant. *1856 J. A. Froude Hist. Eng. (1858) I. iv. 291   The supposed right of the pope to present to English benefices.* And that is the one I would and do take licence to use in everyday circumstances, e.g. for people "presenting for interview". I take your point entirely about "present yourself" being transitive.